# Change %Y-%m%d to %Y%m (csv manipulation)

Tags: python, csv

Taking data from a CSV file, trying to change the dates to the right format (ie change from 2016-12-25 to 2016-12)

This is the code right now:

```
import csv 
csvfile = open('XML_project.csv') 
linesreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
from re import sub
from decimal import Decimal
import statistics as s
import datetime

date = []
for l in linesreader:
    #date manipulation
    temp = l[4]
    temp_two = datetime.datetime.strptime(temp, "%Y-%m")
    date.append(twmp_two)
csvfile.close
```

It says the file has unconverted data and I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Please edit your post to put triple backticks around your code - it will preserve the formatting and indentation:

````
```
your code
goes here
```
````

That said, I think your problem is the call to `strptime()`. If you also include the full stack trace that came with the error this should be evident (with the `strptime()` call at the top of the stack). It might also help to see a few lines of example CSV data.

Anyway, you have this:

```
temp_two = datetime.datetime.strptime(temp, "%Y-%m")
```

Suppose you have the date `2021-12-25`: `strptime` will only match the `2021-12` part. That is no doubt your aim, but `strptime` likes to parse the entire string - that way you have more confidence that you have a *correct* `"%Y-%m"` format string.

So you want:

```
temp_two = datetime.datetime.strptime(temp, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

That should match the whole date field (therefore no error). Then you want to produce a new YYYY-mm style string for your dates, from that datetime object, like this:

```
yyyy_mm = temp_two.strftime("%Y-%m")
```

which you can then store:

```
date.append(yyyy_mm)
```

Minor other remarks:

- it is normal to put all the imports at the top of your file (makes them easy to see)
- it is typical to import specific names from the `datetime` module because of the unfortunately same-named `datetime` class

Eg:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

which lets you use `datetime.strptime()` instead of the more cumbersome `datetime.datetime.strptime()`.